# Why do some questions use a yellow background? — Pourquoi certaines questions sont-elles sur fond jaune ?

Tags: support

Je ne trouve pas de réponse à cette question dans le « help center », ni à partir des « tags »; quelle rubrique comporte ce code et possiblement tous les codes couleur de cette sorte et autres codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, until now, only one such color code exists. It's used to highlight questions that match the chosen “watched tags”.

À ma connaissance il n'existe  qu'un de ces codes couleurs, et il correspond aux questions qui posèdent des tags de la « watch list » que l'utilisateur a choisis.